# React formatting HTML element properties from multiple sources

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am iterating over state that holds the data for cards like

```
cards: [
        { id: 1, name: "p1", value: "Prize 1", imageSrc: "/path/to/image", bgColor: { background: "#FF6384", border: "4px solid #FF6384" }, isVisible: "" },
```

in my iteration, I am using a ternary to determine one of the classes like

```
<div className={`prize-card ${this.state.flipped === card ? "flipped" : ""} `} onClick={() => this.clickHandler(card)}>
```

I see how I can use the ternary to determine a second class on top of standard "prize-card", but how would I add even a third class based on the bgColor state? In a standard HTML element, I can just:

```
<div className={card.bgColor}>
```

But I can't figure out the syntax on how to add the {card.bgColor} to the rest of the className below... the bgColor below is wrapped in asterisks to show what I cannot add without errors.

```
<div className={ **{card.bgColor}**`prize-card ${this.state.flipped === card ? "flipped" : ""} `} onClick={() => this.clickHandler(card)}>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: its js to concat variables and strings you use the `+` sign or with template literals you use the dollar sign before your brackets, just as you did with your if statment

Comment: Hey is the card.bgColor jsx style or just a className

Comment: Ranjan, card.bgColor is a stored state that includes a set of styles. If you look at the first piece of code, the card states, you will see the bgColor.